# In a $∆ABC$ if $\angle C=90$ and area is $\frac{1}{2}$ square units. Let minimum possible value of hypotenuse as $\lambda$ then

Tags: geometry, inequality

> In a $∆ABC$ if $\angle C=90$ and area is $\frac{1}{2}$ square units. Let the minimum possible value of hypotenuse as $\lambda$ then find whether $\lambda$ is rational or irrational also find the value of $\lambda^4+\lambda^2$

Considering the other two sides as $a,b$
We get $a^2+b^2=\lambda^2$ {by Pythagoras theorem}
and value of $ab=1$. Substituting $a=\frac{1}{b}$ in the first equation we get $$b^2\lambda^2-(b^4+1)=0$$
How to proceed now?

Comment: If $\lambda^2=b^2+\frac1{b^2}$, you want to minimize $b^2+\frac1{b^2}$

Comment: Think symmetry. This is not only a right triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1:

Continuing OP's work:
Using $AM-GM$, we note that the minimum of $b^2+\frac1{b^2}$ is $2$, and so $\lambda _{min} =\sqrt2$.

### Method 2:

Let $\angle BAC=\alpha$. So, $b=\lambda\cdot \cos(\alpha)$ and $a=\lambda\cdot \sin(\alpha)$. Since $ab=1:$

$$1=\lambda^2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha) \implies 2=\lambda^2 \sin(2\alpha) \implies \lambda^2_{min}=2$$ Once again, $$\lambda _{min} =\sqrt2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $A.M.-G.M.$ inequality

$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}=\sqrt{a^2b^2}=1$$

$$ \lambda^2=2$$

$$\lambda=\sqrt2$$

Clearly $\lambda=\sqrt2$ is irrational.

$\lambda^4+\lambda^2=6$

Answer (score 1):

When you set up the equation $b^2\lambda^2-(b^4+1)=0$, you could have gone ahead from there.

Rewriting, $b^4 - b^2 \lambda^2 + 1 = 0$. Considering it as a quadratic equation in variable $b^2$, we must have its discriminant as non-negative for real solutions.

So, $\lambda^4 - 4 \geq 0 \implies \lambda \geq \sqrt2$.

Checking the sum and product of roots, it is clear that we get positive roots for $\lambda \geq \sqrt2 \ $ (as the quadratic is in $b^2$, this check should be done).